# How can we center FA Icons within a Boostrap grid?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, font-awesome

I'm using the Bootstrap grid system to display some FA Icons within a small grid. I've been attempting to make them evenly aligned horizontally to no avail, here is what they currently look like:

[image: FA Icon Centering Issue]

Please see my code below:

```
<div class="col-sm col-md-4 text-center">
    <span class="info-box-text"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name this icon..." style="text-align: center;"/></span>
    <div class="col-sm col-md-12 block-center" style="margin-top: 10px;">
        <div class="col-sm-3"><i class="fa fa-info"></i></div>
        <div class="col-sm-3"><i class="fa fa-crosshairs"></i></div>
        <div class="col-sm-3"><i class="fa fa-question"></i></div>
        <div class="col-sm-3"><i class="fa fa-flag-o"></i></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm col-md-12">
        <div class="col-sm-3"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></div>
        <div class="col-sm-3"><i class="fa fa-tachometer"></i></div>
        <div class="col-sm-3"><i class="fa fa-power-off"></i></div>
        <div class="col-sm-3"><i class="fa fa-play"></i></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm col-md-12">
        <div class="col-sm-3"><i class="fa fa-tint"></i></div>
        <div class="col-sm-3"><i class="fa fa-ban"></i></div>
        <div class="col-sm-3"><i class="fa fa-cogs"></i></div>
        <div class="col-sm-3"><i class="fa fa-bolt"></i></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm col-md-12">
        <div class="col-sm-3"><i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i></div>
        <div class="col-sm-3"><i class="fa fa-stethoscope"></i></div>
        <div class="col-sm-3"><i class="fa fa-gear"></i></div>
        <div class="col-sm-3"><i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm col-md-12">
        <div class="col-sm-3"><i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i></div>
        <div class="col-sm-3"><i class="fa fa-pause"></i></div>
        <div class="col-sm-3"><i class="fa fa-exclamation"></i></div>
        <div class="col-sm-3"><i class="fa fa-asterisk"></i></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the `fa-fw` class.
It sets the icons width to the same fixed width.
You can read more in the docs https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/styling/fixed-width-icons

Comment: Thanks for the quick and painless solution.

Answer (score 1):

You should put your inner cols (col-sm-3) inside of a row for them to behave properly.

Like this:

```
<div class="col-sm col-md-4 text-center">
        <span class="info-box-text"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name this icon..." style="text-align: center;"/></span>
        <div class="row" style="margin-top: 10px;">
            <div class="col-sm-3"><i class="fa fa-info"></i></div>
            <div class="col-sm-3"><i class="fa fa-crosshairs"></i></div>
            <div class="col-sm-3"><i class="fa fa-question"></i></div>
            <div class="col-sm-3"><i class="fa fa-flag-o"></i></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></div>
            <div class="col-sm-3"><i class="fa fa-tachometer"></i></div>
            <div class="col-sm-3"><i class="fa fa-power-off"></i></div>
            <div class="col-sm-3"><i class="fa fa-play"></i></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3"><i class="fa fa-tint"></i></div>
            <div class="col-sm-3"><i class="fa fa-ban"></i></div>
            <div class="col-sm-3"><i class="fa fa-cogs"></i></div>
            <div class="col-sm-3"><i class="fa fa-bolt"></i></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3"><i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i></div>
            <div class="col-sm-3"><i class="fa fa-stethoscope"></i></div>
            <div class="col-sm-3"><i class="fa fa-gear"></i></div>
            <div class="col-sm-3"><i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3"><i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i></div>
            <div class="col-sm-3"><i class="fa fa-pause"></i></div>
            <div class="col-sm-3"><i class="fa fa-exclamation"></i></div>
            <div class="col-sm-3"><i class="fa fa-asterisk"></i></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Cols don't behave properly inside of other cols, its always best to use Row->col->row->col format.

Comment: Thank you, I recently learned this and I didn't realize I hadn't fixed it this portion of code